# MongoDump query with BinData

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

The Mongodump documentation specifies you can dump using a specific query

i.e.

```
mongodump --host localhost --db mydb --collection testCollection --query "{SomeKey: 'some value'}"
```

I'm storing _ids fields as BinData, is it possible to query on this?

I've tried

```
mongodump --host localhost --db mydb --collection testCollection --query "{_id: 'BinData(3,ryBRQ+Px0kGRsZofJhHgqg==)'}"
```

With no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This needs a lot of escaping, unfortunately. Also, you'll have to use the [`$binary`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) representation instead, e.g.

```
mongodump --host localhost --db test --collection bd --query 
"{\"_id\" : { \"$binary\" : \"ryBRQ+Px0kGRsZofJhHgqg==\", \"$type\" : \"03\" } }"
```

Note that `$type` must be a hex string, not a number.

In linux, you'll also have to escape the `$` to `\$`.

Comment: I tried this, it ran, but with no matching results.  In MongoVue, I can see my _id field is stored as Binary - 3:UuidLegacy, which is also the same type as you stipulated within your query.  I've no idea why it returns nothing.  I tried to run the unescaped query you provided within MongoVue and it didn't yield any results either.

Comment: I tested this on my win7 machine before posting it and it worked. Are you running linux or windows? Which mongo version do you run? (mine: 2.5.4)

Comment: I am running 2.2.2, Windows 7.

Comment: Can you upgrade MongoDB? (either to 2.2.7 or 2.4.9 which is the current stable release), 2.2.2 is museumware

Comment: Human error on my part, I confirmed it works on 2.2.2 and 2.4.9.  Also, upvote for "museumware".  I am using it in a professional capacity, so an upgrade can't be considered.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to escape that much. You may just use single-quote outside of the query and double-quote inside, i.e. But beware to have the type as hex, meaning "03" and not "3"

```
mongodump --host localhost --db test --collection bd --query
'{"_id" : { "$binary" : "ryBRQ+Px0kGRsZofJhHgqg==", "$type" : "03" } }'
```